# Edit text tricks..

Tags: java, android

without using any button.. after writing values or text in an edit text , can we show the values in another text view?  the contents written inside the edit text will be automatically fetched and will be printed on another text view.  Is this possible in Android studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  addTextChangedListener method and TextWatcher class to do any task after text is changed in EditText.

Following code may help:

```
EditText txt= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittxt); 
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text); 

txt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

//Code here executes when text in editext changes

textview.setText(txt.getText().toString();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to changes in the EditText and update other views as you wish.
Here's a helpful article: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-edittext-text-change-listener.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

You can add a TextChangedListener to listen for changes on the edittext and update the textview accordingly.